# How to change string into list

Tags: python

Hi I want change a string into an list like:

```
'[KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, DOWNLOADMODE.FWTOFW, False, DEPLOYMODE.DEPLOY]'
```

into

```
[KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, DOWNLOADMODE.FWTOFW, False, DEPLOYMODE.DEPLOY]
```

Comment: Is `KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY` supposed to be a string? Some constant looked up elsewhere? The end result you're describing isn't a legal `list` literal, so you need to be more clear here. A complete [MCVE] would be ideal (not only making it clear what you want, but showing some effort).

Comment: If security is not an issue, you can just do eval(list_string) - eval evaluates a string as code.

Comment: `eval` evaluates a string as python, but be very careful regarding the source of your strings as it can be a security issue.

Comment: If security is not an issue, you can just do eval(list_string) - eval evaluates a string as code.

Comment: eval will only work here if KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY is some kind of defined value, and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a simple function to deal with this, using split and replace:

Assuming that ‘stringlist’ is your string’d list...

```
def transformlist(stringlist):
    stringlist = stringlist.split(sep=',')
    stringlist[0] = stringlist[0].replace('[','')
    stringlist[-1] = stringlist[-1].replace(']','')
    return stringlist
```

Comment: This evaluates to strings not variables

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.split()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) then [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

s = '[KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, DOWNLOADMODE.FWTOFW, False, DEPLOYMODE.DEPLOY]'

def get_val(value):
    values = value.split('.')
    if values[0] in locals: return getattr(getattr(locals, value), values[1])
    if values[0] in globals: return getattr(getattr(globals, value), values[1])
    try: return ast.literal_eval(value)
    except: return value

#slice the string to get rid of the brackets
#and .replace to remove all spaces
data = [get_val(val) for val in s[1:-1].replace(' ', '').split(',')]
```

This is probably the safe way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most succinct way is use the `re` module to split and remove symbols from the string, then recombine the strings back into a `list` data structure:

```
import re

s = '[KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, KEYTYPE.FWPROD2KEY, DOWNLOADMODE.FWTOFW, False, DEPLOYMODE.DEPLOY]'

l_str = ''.join(re.split(', [ ]', s))
l = eval(l_str)
```

or a one-liner:

```
l = eval(''.join(re.split(', [ ]', s)))
```

To [Arya's points in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227662/how-to-change-string-into-list#comment95281186_54227662) since I don't have those variables defined I can't test it, but you should then be able to verify the result is of type `list`:

```
>>> print(type(l))
<type 'list'>
```